# jqgrid: import CSV file?

Tags: jquery, csv, jqgrid

I'm trying to design a web page that'll allow a user to load a spreadsheet file (can be a simple CSV file) into a GUI table. He/she can edit it within the browser as he/she likes. And then submit it to the server side in php.

Right now I'm looking at jqgrid. But I haven't seen any example of importing CSV file into the grid. Has anyone done this before with jqgrid? Or any other JS library?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid has no support for importing of CSV file.

You should first read the data in the JavaScript objects and then use `datatype:'jsonstring'` to fill the grid with the data. If you import read the CSV file on the server you can use `datatype:'json'`.